# How to make Ctrl/Shift+KP_Insert perform copy/paste in Linux terminals.

Tags: linux, keyboard, terminal

On my laptop keyboard I don't have dedicated insert/delete keys - there are only numpad ones located at the same buttons as "0" and ".". Xev displays that these have KP_Insert and KP_Delete keysyms, while the dedicated ones have Insert and Delete keysyms.

Now, in gnome-terminal, lxterminal and some other terminal emulators, pressing Ctrl+KP_Insert/Shift+KP_insert works as copy/paste, but in st, urxvt and others it does nothing. Is there a way to configure the latter ones to behave similar to the first ones?

Is this something that I should configure for a specific terminal emulator or can it be done system-wide (for example, assigning Insert/Delete keysyms to these buttons)?

Answer (score 2):

`st` and `urxvt` will copy the text as soon as you select it, without additional commands. The classical way of pasting into those terminals is to middle click, with middle button emulation activated if needed (which makes left+right act like middle button.)

To remap the button, your best bet is probably `xmodmap`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want copypaste on linux char console, it won't work. It needs a sophisticated rpc/ole feature which only on gui exists.

If you want this on X: it is not the job of your terminal emulator, but your gui environment. Although it is possible for the terminal emulators to override/change the normal settings of your gui. Dig deep in the keyboard shortcut settings everywhere (in your terminal settings and in the settings of your gui environment too), you can have luck.

If nothing works, it is posdible to change the keyboard mapping of the X server, too. There is the xmodmap command line tool, but there are also nicer gui apps for this. It depends on your windowing environment, which distro do you use, ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want it on X, but I'm not running any DE, just X11 + dwm + terminal. As of distribution, I'm using Fedora.